# Sorting NoSQL data into a Relational Database

Tags: oracle, mongodb, web-crawler, dashboard

Hi guys i need a nudge in the right direction please

So i have a final year project that requires me to make use of a webcrawler to populate a NoSQL database(MongoDB at request of the lecturer). Then we have to filter/merge/sort(for lack of better understanding?) the NoSQL data into a Relational database that we can then use to generate reports with a dashboard.

Alot of words with very little guidance. I have spent hours looking into this subject and im nowhere near an answer.

So im calling on the collective minds of a bunch of IT pros to help me and 5 other guys finish our degree

We have a relative understanding of how crawlers work and should be able to populate the mongoDB with that information(we are crawling realtor websites for information regarding houses and apartments)

I have a very good relational database background as we spent a lot of time in that are

the problem i am running into is that i do not get how we can sort the nosql data into the Oracle database that we set up and im running out of time.

Any suggestions?
Thanks guys!

Comment: Depends on the data that you are importing, but if I am not mistaken Oracle has a Json data type.  You can map the first level of a json object to columns in a database and if there is any sub object just map those to a JSON column if you are short on time, otherwise map to another table with a foreign key.  Setting up the table properly you would just need to paginate results from the NoSQL db and insert into Oracle.

Comment: Thanks ill have a look into that